Are the DMG's "How PCs Improve" Options...Balanced?
The PHB says that characters level up between adventures, partly through training. Page 197 of the DMG provides optional rules to more explicitly describe this training, but...
Its rule for Gaining Class Benefits costs 1000 gp to reach 2nd level. According to the Wealth By Level table, that's more than a 2nd level character's entire net worth, never mind all the armor and potions they probably want to buy. 3rd and 4th levels take 2000 gp each--the total cost of their levels by 4th are 5000gp, which is still nearly their entire expected Wealth By Level.
Am I misreading these training rules, or are they meant to be paired with some other alterations that simply aren't mentioned (should you just give out this amount of gold as extra, basically nullifying the point of the cost?), or is the intent actually to run the party's coffers this dry?
And if there is some actual balancing mistake present here, is it addressed in any later books?

I don't have the information handy so I won't make it a fully comment yet, but I believe this is a tag back to AD&D where you didn't just "(Ding) Level up!". My uncertainty is that I don't remember if it was a house rule I bumped into at multiple tables.

Table 5–1: Character Wealth by Level tracks wealth—value that you have. It doesn’t track income or expenses, only the net value overall of whatever you’re left with.
Income is tracked by the various encounter reward and loot tables, primarily Table 3–3: Treasure Values per Encounter. Expenses, obviously, don’t have any unified table, but certainly the various books discuss the prices of all sorts of things you might pay for.
The Dungeon Master’s Guide doesn’t do a great job being clear about the meaning of “wealth” in this context, but the fact that Table 3–3 and Table 5–1 intentionally don’t line up, and the discussion of that fact, confirms that this is how they’re using it. As they note, if you rigorously follow Table 3–3, PCs wind up with more money than is listed on Table 5–1. They explain that this is because they expect PCs to spend a certain amount of their earnings on things they don’t get to keep (primarily, by their estimation, in the form of consumables that get consumed). One of the things they warn you about is if your PCs don’t buy consumables, or don’t wind up consuming them, their wealth may exceed the recommendation in Table 5–1, at which point you might want to reduce the loot they see accordingly.
Ultimately, that’s the point of Table 5–1: if PCs wind up away from the values shown for any reason, the idea is that the DM should nudge things towards the proper values, subtly adding to or taking away from loot piles in future encounters so that the PCs eventually return to the expectations. That includes any of the leveling options, or anything else. There is no need for those leveling options to account for this issue, because Table 5–1 effectively already accounts for this (and anything else).
(On the other hand, Table 3–3 won’t serve you so well in such a campaign, because if you’re gaining income based on 3–3 and spending some of it to level up, you won’t keep up with Table 5–1. However, this is kind of “normal” anyway, because Table 3–3 is very much a default, and already has some wiggle room for consumables built into its values. You just wind up having to “wiggle” more in such a campaign.)

I personally think this can be a way to limit the resource that your PC have access to.
Rather than considering whether it is balanced or not, I would suggest you consider "what would happen if you introduce this rule to your table". Always put the experience of your PC first when you make up your rule.
For example, if your PC is unlikely to reach the amount of wealth needed for leveling up, the game would end up either you provide some extra ways for them to make money, or they would become underpowered and hence the future challenges would be more difficult for them than what they are supposed to be.
Or, if they already have the wealth far more than enough, then having this rule or not actually doesn't change the way they play, except now they have to go to a city to level up.
In game design perspective, I think this would only slow down the game play (since now the players require 2 instead of 1 resource for leveling up) and is not bringing more fun than before. If you feel this rule can bring certain flavor you are looking for in your world, or if you have some specific balancing requirements need to fulfil and this rule can help you, go ahead.
My table can be an example. During a certain period of time, my PCs are quite poor and underpowered. I had to give them some side quests (which also opened some new quest lines later on, but I wasn't planning that far at that moment) for them to make some extra money, so that they can gear up and get prepare for the next main quest. If you feel that your PC might have trouble gaining the coins for leveling up, that might be something you have to do in your campaign.
For me, I would suggest just focusing on the part your PCs are most interested in, and try to remove the rest as much as possible (like now my table has not touched the majority of the combat system for quite a while, since they are simply enjoying the story and social events most of the time). So, it would highly depend on how your PCs handle your game if this is a suitable rule for your campaign.
